# How can I ignore failure of a container in multi-container pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a multi-container application: app + sidecar. Both containers suppose to be alive all the time but sidecar is not really that important.
Sidecar depends on external resource, if this resource is not available - sidecar crashes. And it takes entire pod down. Kubernetes tries to recreate pod and fails because sidecar now won't start.
But from my business logic perspective - crash of sidecar is absolutely normal. Having that sidecar is nice but not mandatory.
I don't want sidecar to take main app with it when it crashes.
What would be best Kubernetes-native way to achieve that?
Is it possible to tell kubernetes ignore failure of sidecar as a "false positive" event which is absolutely fine?

I can't find anything in pod specification what controls that behaviour.

My yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: logs-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: ${IMAGE}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9009
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs-dir
          mountPath: /usr/src/app/logs
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: "512Mi"
        readinessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 60 
          failureThreshold: 8 
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 8 
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTP
            path: /myapp/v1/admin-service/git-info
            port: 9009
      - name: graylog-sidecar
        image: digiapulssi/graylog-sidecar:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs-dir
          mountPath: /log
        env:
        - name: GS_TAGS
          value: "[\"myapp\"]"
        - name: GS_NODE_ID
          value: "nodeid"
        - name: GS_SERVER_URL
          value: "${GRAYLOG_URL}"
        - name: GS_LIST_LOG_FILES
          value: "[\"/ctwf\"]"
        - name: GS_UPDATE_INTERVAL
          value: "10"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "0.1"
```

Comment: What about just redesigning the sidecar container such that if the external resource isn't available, it either retries or blocks instead of exiting with a failure?

Comment: @stqs can you post the yaml?

Comment: @larsks, I was thinking about it but its is some 3rd party sidecar, so, don't wanna take another component for myself to maintain, it would be awesome to use it as it is

Comment: How about defining the sidecar container livenessProbe to no-op?

Comment: @garlicFrancium, sample added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom livenessProbe should help but for your scenario I would use the liveness for your main app container which is the `myapp`. 
 Considering the fact that you don't care about the sidecare (as mentioned). I would set the pod `restartPolicy` to `Never` and then define a custom livelinessProbe for your main `myapp`. In this way the Pod will never restart doesn't matter which container is failed but when your `myapp` container's liveliness fails `kubelet` will restart the container! Ref below, [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#example-states)

> Pod is running and has two Containers. Container 1 exits with failure.
>
> Log failure event. If restartPolicy is: Always: Restart Container; Pod
>   phase stays Running. OnFailure: Restart Container; Pod phase stays
>   Running. Never: Do not restart Container; Pod phase stays Running.

so the updated (pseudo) yaml should look like below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        ...
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - {{ your custom liveliness check command goes }}
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        readinessProbe:
          ...
      - name: graylog-sidecar
        ...
```

Note: since I don't know your application therefore I cannot write the command but for my jboss server I use this (an example for you)

```
livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --commands="read-attribute
              server-state"
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Comment: If I try this, my Pod stops running after liveness probe failure, as it should, since restartPolicy is Never.

Comment: I either get "unable to recognize "my-deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1" for "apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1", or "invalid: spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: "Always"" for apiVersion: apps/v1.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning:** the answer that was flagged as "correct" does not appear to work.

Adding a Liveness Probe to the application container and setting Restart Policy to "Never", will lead to the Pod being stopped and **never restarted** in a scenario where  the sidecar container has stopped and the application container has failed its Liveness Probe. This is a problem, since you DO want the restarts for the application container.

The problem should be solved as follows:

- Tweak your sidecar container in the startup command to keep the main process running on failure of the application process. This could be done with an extra piece of scripting, e.g. by appending `| tail -f /dev/null` to the startup command.
- Adding a Liveness Probe to the application container is in general a good idea. Keep in mind though that it only protects you against a scenario where your application process keeps running without your application being in a correct state. It will certainly not overwrite the restartPolicy:

> livenessProbe: Indicates whether the container is running. If the liveness probe fails, the kubelet kills the container, and the container is subjected to its restart policy. If a Container does not provide a liveness probe, the default state is Success.
> [Container Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)

Comment: This solution is not much better. Yes, sidecar container will be preserved, but why do we need it if command failed.
One of possible solutions can be to run not command you need in sidecar container, but command which run the command you need in the background and check if it's running. If not - rerun.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution which works for me is not to fail inside a sidecar container, but just log an error and rerun.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
# do some stuff which can fail on start

set +e # needed to not exit if command fails

while ! command; do
    echo "command failed - rerun"
done
```

This will always rerun the `command` if it fails, but exit if the `command` finished successfully.

Comment: It doesn't work, you try to kill the script, it will kill the command process and will restart it.

Comment: @DavidBarda Works for me. I use similar logic for metrics exporter in sidecar container. I did not follow the part about "you try to kill the script"

Comment: @Pavel , did you try to terminate the script using sigint?

Answer (score -1):

You can define a custom livenessProbe for your sidecar to have greater failureThreshold / periodSeconds to accommodate what is considered acceptable failure rate in your environment, or simply ignore all failure.

Docs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#probe-v1-core

`kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.containers.livenessProbe`

Comment: Could you specify how to "simply ignore all failure"? I guess that's what is in question!

Comment: The miniumum value for both `failureThreshold ` and `periodSeconds` is 1. I don't see any wild card for infinite time!

Comment: If you set large enough `periodSeconds` and large enough `failureThreshold`, this will give you a large enough window of how long container can remain in failed state without being restarted. If you just want to have an infinite time, then can define `livenessProbe.exec` to run something like `exit 0` or `/bin/true` in order to always pass the check.

From docs:
failureThreshold <integer>
     Minimum consecutive failures for the probe to be considered failed after
     having succeeded. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1.

Comment: i think livenessProbe commands `exit 0` and `/bin/true` are ran inside the specific container, therefore this approach will work when you have the container alive but if the container is dead already how do you run the commands? is there any examples you have?

Comment: @garlicFrancium If you can't run commands in the container for some reason, try a noop probe: 

          livenessProbe:
            periodSeconds: 1000000000
            failureThreshold: 1000
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/true

In theory this runs every 32 years, and needs to fail a 1000 times for the probe to be considered as failed. Consider not doing this, it sort of works against what k8s is trying to help with.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation there! it helps btw what does "noop probe" mean?

Comment: @garlicFrancium Glad it was useful. "noop" just means "no operation", it does nothing, more detail here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)
And "probe" refers to Kubernetes liveness and readiness probes as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/, for a quick intro check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxEvAPQRwhw