# How to mark Pod as ready if one of the containers has completed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

I have a `Pod` that has two regular (i.e. not `Init`) `Container`s. One of them is meant to be used as a "job", i.e. it should run a script and then exit while the other container should keep running. The problem is that as soon as the "job" container is finished, the `Pod` will be marked as `NotReady` due to all containers not being `Ready`. Can I somehow make this "job" container for Pod-readiness optional? Is there anything better than having `sleep 1000000000` in the "job" container's command?

Note that:

- I cannot make this "job" container an `InitContainer` because it cannot run before the other container
- I *could* use a k8s `Job` for that although it'd be way easier for my specific use-case to run this "job" container in the same Pod as I'd like it to share network and some volumes with the other container. `Job`s unfortunately cannot "bind" to an existing `Pod`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ignore failure of a container in multi-container pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593518/how-can-i-ignore-failure-of-a-container-in-multi-container-pod)

Comment: I think the best solution is simply to run `sleep inf` in the "job" container when it is done. Alternately, just make it a `Job`: while it can't bind to the same pod, it *can* share volumes with the pod (e.g., via persistent volume claims), and it can access pod network services via `Service` objects.

Comment: whats the job container actually do? may be there are other way around to get the desired with pod life cycle event

Comment: «One of them is meant to be used as a "job", i.e. it should run a script and then exit while the other container should keep running.» That sounds to me like the definition of initContainer. Can you explain why it can't be an initContainer?